# process communication: send * commands, why looping

Tags: c, pipe, fork, dup2

I'm trying to start a child process and sending him commands trought pipe. And i think i miss a concept that i don't know.

The first command sending is a success, the other failed, and it gave me an infinite loop.  And i dont understand why.

**parent.c**

```
int invoke_proc(int out_tube[2]) {

    pid_t pid; 
    int rv; 
    int tube[2];

    if(pipe (tube)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "pipe");
        exit(1);
    }

    pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "fork");
        exit(1);
    }

    // parent
    if(pid) {
        close(tube[0]);
        out_tube[1] = tube[1];
    }

    // child
    else {
        close(tube[1]);
        dup2(tube[0], 0);
        execl("child", "child", NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int tube[2];
    //for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        invoke_proc(tube);

        sleep(2);
        write(tube[1], "allo\n", 7);
        printf("!\n");

        sleep(5);
        write(tube[1], "bye bye\n", 10);
        printf("!\n");

        sleep(5);
        write(tube[1], "exit\n", 10);
        printf("!\n");

        close(tube[1]);

    //}
    return 0;
}
```

**child.c**

```
int main() {
    char string[100];

    printf("Child Process: [%d]\n", getpid()); 
    printf("-------------\n"); 

    do{ 
        printf("Enter Command: "); 

        fflush(stdout); 

        fgets(string, 100, stdin); 
        printf("[%s]\n",string);    

    } while(strcmp(string, "exit"));
    return 0;   
}
```

here is the output:

> -bash-4.1$ ./parent
>      Child Process: [61983]
>
> ---
>
> Enter Command: [allo
>
> ]
>
> !
>
> Enter Command: !
>
> []
>
> Enter Command: ^C
>
> -bash-4.1$

i ended the process, otherwise it will give me an infinite loop after this.

I'm reading similar questions, but i can't find the answer.  if possible, please, answer as simple as possible.

Thanx.

p.s and yes..this is a school work. My goal is to send the same command to multiple child.  But i'm trying to get out of this step first.

Comment: Wow, a school work… Sorry for an offtop, but you have a really cool school. For I tried get an education in an institute at programmer specialty, they didn't even gave C in the first course, I had to learn everything by myself. You're very-very lucky ☺

Answer (score 0):

Nvm, i found the solution from another source: http://www.makelinux.net/alp/038

I'm converting the file descriptor to a File *, and write into it.

Not sure, but it does what i need.

Tx.